# java rmi multiple clients same application

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I am trying to do an RMI mastermind application in java, where each client needs a separate game from the server, but somehow the combinations for each new client that runs are appended to one game, so it is as if each new client joins the main game.

Here is my server code:

```
public class MastermindServer
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException
{
    try
    {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1111);

        System.out.println("RMI registry ready...");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception starting RMI registry");
    }

    Naming.rebind("//localhost:1111/MastermindServer", new MastermindImplementation());

}
}
```

and my client code:

```
public class MastermindClient
{
    private static MastermindMenuGUI menuFrame;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("before try catch");

    try {

        Registry clientRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1111);
        System.out.println("Client registry " + clientRegistry);

        MastermindInterface game = (MastermindInterface) clientRegistry.lookup("theGame") ;
        System.out.println("Client ready");

        System.out.println(game.createCombination());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception in client");
    }
    } 
}
```

How do I make a new separate game for each client?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The object in the Registry should be a factory object. The client should look it up and then call a factory method which returns a new game, which should be another remote object.